# Django: Display different data from a view based on URL using if elif

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views

I have about 1000 records worth of data and I would like to display the subsets of that data in the same template file based on category. I am having trouble finding a solution that really works. Below is what I have so for but I am pretty sure there is a much more efficient way to do this.

**View**

```
def man_org_list(request):
    manufacturers = Organization.objects.filter(member__member_flag=1, member__member_type='Manufacturer').order_by('id')
    suppliers = Organization.objects.filter(member__member_flag=1, member__member_type='Supplier').order_by('id')
    distributor = Organization.objects.filter(member__member_flag=1, member__member_type='distributor').order_by('id')
    return render(request, 'profiles/man_dash.html', {'man': manufacturers, 'sup': suppliers, 'dist': distributor})
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.org_list, name='org_list'),
    url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.org_details, name='org_details'),
    url(r'^man_dash/', views.man_org_list, name='man_org_list')
]
```

**Part of the code I am trying to change base on category:**

```
{% if request.get_full_path == '/profiles/man_dash/manufacturers/' %}
  {% for org in man %}
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">{{ org.id }}</th>
        <td>{{ org.org_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ org.org_type }}</td>
        {% for member in org.member.all %}
        <td>{{ member.member_flag }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
        {% for c_score in org.c_score.all %}
        <td>{{ c_score.completeness_score }}%</td>
        {% endfor %}
        <td><a href="{% url 'org_details' org.id %}" target="_blank">View</a></td>
      </tr>
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

As you can see in the snippet I am using request.get_full_path to match the url path to display the data. However, using this approach I would have to copy over the same block of code 3 times with only one page changing which makes me beliave that this is not the ideal way to do this.

Is there a better way to do this maybe through the view or url.py?

Answer (score 0):

I;m not sure if that is what you need but lets try.

First of all it seems you url will not match properly:

Lets add `member_type` argument that will be captured from an url

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.org_list, name='org_list'),
    url(r'^(?P\d+)/$', views.org_details, name='org_details'),
    url(r'^man_dash/<str:member_type>/', views.man_org_list, name='man_org_list')
]
```

Now add the kwarg to the view:

```
def man_org_list(request, member_type=None):
    member_type_map = {
        'manufacturers': 'Manufacturer',
        'suppliers': 'Supplier',
        'distributors': 'distributor'
    }

    member_type = member_type_map.get(member_type, None)
    if member_type is None:
        raise Http404
    queryset = Organization.objects.filter(member__member_flag=1, member__member_type=member_type).order_by('id')
    return render(request, 'profiles/man_dash.html', {'object_list': queryset})
```

Now your template needs only to iterate over a list of objects

```
{% for org in object_list %}
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">{{ org.id }}</th>
        <td>{{ org.org_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ org.org_type }}</td>
        {% for member in org.member.all %}
        <td>{{ member.member_flag }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
        {% for c_score in org.c_score.all %}
        <td>{{ c_score.completeness_score }}%</td>
        {% endfor %}
        <td><a href="{% url 'org_details' org.id %}" target="_blank">View</a></td>
      </tr>
  {% endfor %}
```

Comment: thanks for a quick response. I see how you doing that which makes a lot of sence. However, I am getting 'The current path, profiles/man_dash/suppliers/, didn't match any of these.'

Comment: I also noticed that on the line member_type = member_type.map.get(member_type, None), member_type.map should be member_type_map but that still did not resolve the issue.